# Контекстное меню ПКМ Windows

Tags: windows, реестр

Мне необходимо что бы моя программа была доступна из контекстного меню при нажатии ПКМ, но только у картинок (хотя бы просто что бы оно было доступно). На [CyberForum](https://www.cyberforum.ru/windows/thread617978.html) я прочел о том что надо редактировать раздел `Компьютер\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` в реестре. Соответственно я добавляю туда раздел Some. Теперь при нажатии ПКМ по некоторой папке появляется пункт меню Some[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но при нажатии ПКМ на некоторый файл такого меню не появляется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как его туда добавить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Найдите `Компьютер\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`
2. Там создайте папку с именем, которое хотите видеть в контекстном меню (Notepad, к примеру)
3. В этой папке создайте папку `command`
4. В папке `command` значение ключа `(Default)` установите таким образом: `"Путь" "%1"`, где Путь - путь к программе, которая должна открыть файл. К примеру `"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" "%1"`

Comment: А если я нажимаю на некторый файл и таким образом вызываю некоторую программу, будет ли путь к этому файлу передан как аргумент командной строки

Comment: @BlueScreen, да, ```"%1"``` как раз и передает путь к файлу